# Building Android Studio Project using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to build a Android Studio application, by importing it in the studio, but i have one issue.

My Android Studio version (Beta) `0.8.14`.

In my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file distributionUrl:
`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip`

I need to add following change in my `build.gradle` file, under `app` folder 
to build this application.

**Modified file :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'android'

----- Other things -----
```

**Original file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

----- Other things -----
```

If I don't add `buildscript` changes then I get error `Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found`
Why I need to add `buildscript` part, to make it compile.

**UPDATE**

Yes I have Top level `build.gradle` file, which contain following lines:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all   
sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a project build.gradle file and if so what does it contain?

Comment: Yes I have `build.gradle` file, please see my updated question.

Comment: What errors were you getting?

Comment: `Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found`